# Rust ncurses: garbled Chinese characters and setlocale doesn't work

Tags: rust, ncurses

I am trying to print Chinese character in a ncurses screen

```rust
    log::debug!("row str {}", row_str);
    ncurses::addstr(&row_str);
```

variable `row_str` is displayed well in as a parameter of `log::debug` , but get garbled by using `ncurses::addstr`, like this:

```rust
中彖~G潛®弾U // it should be "中文目录"
```

i've tried to fix it by the following 3 methods, but no one works.

```rust
    // method 1
    gettextrs::setlocale(gettextrs::LocaleCategory::LcAll, "");
    // method 2
    use libc::setlocale;
    unsafe {
        setlocale(0, "".as_bytes().as_ptr() as *const i8);
    }
    //method 3
    ncurses::setlocale(ncurses::constants::LcCategory::all, "")
```

Comment: A) Define "garbled". B) Give examples. C) What encoding are you using?

Comment: I'd suggest using one of native rust terminal ui libraries, like Crossterm or Termion(if you don't need windows terminal support) instead.

Comment: @tadman i've update the question and post an example of "garbled charater", i use "utf-8"

Comment: UTF-8 in the source, and your terminal? Just checking as sometimes one of these things slips and stuff like this happens. It's worth checking the bytes here as you might have the right bytes, but the wrong charset.

Comment: @tadman thks for your comments. but i think if the encoding in terminal is not correct, the string in `log::debug!` will not be displayed well.

Comment: One quick test is to use emoji and see if stuff like  shows up, or even a simple accent like `é`. What other encodings do you think might be used?